# Trying to search a Column in a table for certain text

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate, ssrs-2012, show-hide

In the report I want a text box to be visible depending on the information held within a set of data that is usually displayed in a table.

I thought the best way to do this would be to first aggregate the information and then use 'Like' to see if the text can be found within that aggregation.

The issue is that when I do use the aggregate function nothing is displayed as if I put it within an IIF with ISNothing it comes up as true.

Given the dataset I am trying to search is Fields!Conclusion.Value, dsSample, and is only available as a 'First' when looking at the listed Datasets, does anyyone have any suggestions.

Edits:

---

Tried using `=MAX(IIF(Fields!Conclusion.Value = "X", 1, 0), "dsSample")`
Was told by the program "The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox59' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset."

[Image of area of report which is being referenced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O0Cl.png)

The screenshot demonstrates the location of where i would put the calculation (in the smaller text box) and the tables that the information would come from.

Both tables contain the same information, and just are hidden or shown depending on whether the sample description is null or not.
The area being searched is all the results that might come down in the Identification Column.
One example would be shown in [this picture of an example column I am testing it with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J8Q6.png)

I need to be able to find whether any of the results contain the text UMF within them. So in the above information, due to UMF being present I want to be able to unhide a text box that would otherwise be hidden.

Comment: I'm confused. You say you aggregate the data but then say you use an aggregate function. Does `dsSample` just have one record or are there many different `Conclusion` values? Is the value you are looking up static or does it depend on another dataset field? My guess would be something like `=MAX(IIF(Fields!Conclusion.Value = "X", 1, 0), "dsSample")` to find some particular text in another dataset.

Comment: If you are aggregating data, remember that `Null` plus anything results in `Null`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit your question and provide some sample data from your dataset query and expected results .